# Git & SVN on same code base

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a code base that needs to be tracked by both git and svn due to two teams working on the code with different practices.

The problem I am having is that git is storing all the .svn directories in its repo.  I could use a very large .gitignore file and specify every single instance of every .svn directory for every folder but that seems cumbersome.

Is there anything I can do, or am I forced to stop using Git and use SVN & SVN combo with a switch command for different repos?

Is the tool git-svn applicable? Doesnt seem to be from what I can understand.

Thanks.

Comment: What does git-svn *not* do that you need?

Answer (score 7):

Tell one of the teams (preferably the SVN one) to stop being a blocker and use the same VCS the other team uses.

If that's not possible, you'll have to use SVN for the central repository and `git-svn` for the other team.

However, that's pretty messy and you cannot use all the nice features of git - so it would be if the SVN team switched to Git.

Answer (score 3):

Just put `.svn` in your `.gitignore`, Git will match it everywhere in the tree. And yes, `git-svn` may be very useful, *if* the main repo is the SVN one.

Answer (score 0):

Do i understand you right, you have two teams working on the same code, but independent?
I wouldnt do that. Imagine Team 1 changing something on the code and Team 2 doesnt know about it (since it have its own repository). Although if they just share the same code BASE, one could easily use a single repository with branches.

Comment: Independent teams working on the same code is one of the main purposes of VCS. Using VCS enables two teams working on the same code, and how they interact with each other is an organizational issue entirely separate.